# LaTeX Failed to Parse(Unknown Error) on MediaWiki

Tags: latex, parsing, mediawiki

On my wiki implemented by the MediaWiki interface, I am receiving a Failed to Parse (Unknown Error) for the LaTeX in the page. I checked the LocalSettings.php file, and I have set the proper variable($wgUseTeX) to true.

If it helps, the error message before this was a Failed to Parse(Missing texvc executable), but I "fixed" it to the best of my knowledge by running "make" inside the math directory and installing the texvc executable there. I tested texvc and it works on the commandline.

Could there be anything that I am missing?

Comment: Is your Wiki markup sane? e.g., have you tried it on Wikipedia's sandbox? Also, do you get the TeX logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: [MediaWiki Forums LaTeX Error](http://www.mwusers.com/forums/showthread.php?p=42155#post42155)

It seems that I had to clear the math directory except for the original files, rebuild ocaml, and finally rebuild texvc.

Answer (score 2):

```
aptitude install ocaml
cd /math
make clean
make
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to LocalSettings solved it for me.  Just needed to make the directory calls accurate.  Tedious.

```
$wgUseTeX           = true;
$wgUploadDirectory  = "{$IP}/images";
$wgUploadPath       = "{$wgScriptPath}/images";
$wgMathPath         = "{$wgUploadPath}/math";
$wgMathDirectory    = "{$wgUploadDirectory}/math";
$wgTmpDirectory     = "{$wgUploadDirectory}/tmp";
$wgTexvc           = "{$IP}/math/texvc";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the README file](http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/phase3/math/README?view=markup), paying particular attention to "Ensure that the temporary and math directories exist and can be written to by the user account the web server runs under; if you don't control the server, you may have to make them world-writable."

If that does not help, edit render.ml, comment out the block that says "Commenting this block out will aid in debugging", and re-run make. This will leave all temporary files (including the TeX log) so that you can hopefully see what went wrong.

Comment: Where is the TeX log located on a typical Linux server?